# C++ can't establish communication between variables in separate functions

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I am making a text-based RPG with C++ and I'm having the same error pop up time and again, and I'm sure I'm doing something fundamentally wrong, but I don't know what. Searches turned up the solution to the specific compiler error, but not anything I can use to fix the code I'm writing.

**Question I want answered:** How do I use pointers to enable communication of variables between separate functions? In other words, how can I use pointers to point to a variable's value so that I can use and manipulate that value in a function in which it was not declared?

**TL;DR version:** I'm trying to make my "exp" int variable communicate with outside functions using pointers. I get the error "ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]"

**Long version:** Here's a bit of the code where I'm having problems:

In file charlvl.cpp:

```
...
int lvl = 1;
int *exp = 0;//value I want communicated to main()
int str = 0;
int vit = 0;
...
```

in file fight.cpp (main.cpp):

```
...
//you've just killed a monster

cout << "\nThe monster drops to the ground." << endl;
cout << "You gained " << expValue << " experience!" << endl;
&exp += expValue;//&exp is the character's experience.

//expValue is the exp gained upon monster death
//*exp (from charlvl.cpp) is the value I want to communicate to here.
```

It was not declared here, but in charlvl.cpp. How do I establish communication between the declared variable in charlvl.cpp and main() without having to resort to using global variables?

Comment: `*exp += expvalue` is I think what you are looking for.

Comment: Are the variables declared as global variables, or local within a function? Do you allocate memory for the pointer? Why use a pointer if the variable is global, when you can just declare it `extern` in the other source files? Besides the obvious syntax error, there is not enough information to properly answer this question, please post more complete code (see http://sscce.org/ for tips).

Answer (score 2):

If you defined exp as a global pointer, you don't need to think about the communication thing, you can just simply use it in different functions, but the way you use it is wrong.

`&exp += expValue;`

should be change to

`*exp += expValue;`

because `*` means get that pointer's content to me.

btw, try not defining exp as a pointer may also work.

`int exp = 0;`
`exp += expValue;`

This is all based on `exp` is a global var or global pointer.

if you have defined it in a function like this:

```
void func()
{
   int *expPtr = 0;
   int exp = 0
}
```

And you want to use it in another function

```
void use()
{
   // trying to use expPtr or exp.

}
```

The ways I know is:

1, use a local var and return it in `func()`, but be aware that the returned var is only a copy.

```
int func()
{
   int exp = 0;
   exp++;
   return exp;
}
```

2, use a local pointer and allocate memory for it, then return the pointer or assign the new memory to a global pointer. But be careful about the memory leak, you need to delete it as soon as you don't use it.

```
int * func()
{
   int *expPtr = 0;
   expPtr = new int(2);
   return expPtr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've since put exp and expValue and a few other problem variables in namespaces and that cleared up every one of the problems. I just don't like declaring global variables for some reason, which is why I was using pointers, and also for my own education. I'll try changing the signs around even though I tried exactly that in smaller programs and I kept getting the "variable was not declared in this scope" error even with correct pointer syntax.

Comment: Um... I think not using global vars is the OOP mind, I myself believe to use whatever is good, not only using pure OOP.

Answer (score 0):

You've gotten the `&` and `*` operators confused. `*` turns an `int*` into an `int`, while `&` turns an `int*` into an `int**`.

This is what you want:

```
(*exp) += expValue;
```

You might want to consider using references.